# Set image to be the main one

Tags: php

I have a page, where are many images of goods in store.

What I need is that only one image can be set to be the main one by clicking on selected checkbox.

I'm trying to aproach this by having database table where is column 'main' by default value NULL.

Administrator then can set which one of these images will be the main one by simply clicking on checkbox.

Code

```
<?php
foreach ($images as $image) {
<input type="" name="name" value="$image['main']" if($image['main']==1) {
echo 'checked';
} else {
echo '';
}
?>
```

This will output checkbox value to each image.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I need to have only one main image to each product. When I select one checkbox all the others must be disabled or not selected and have value NULL in DB. I don't know how to do that, so I am asking for some guidance.

Comment: Did you have any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected your code, but if that is your problem, you should take a second look at your whole code in your peoject and correct more of your slip of the pen errors :)

```
<?php
foreach ($images as $image)
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="$image['main']" ';

    if($image['main']==1) 
    {
        echo 'checked="checked"';
    }

    echo ' />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's not the problem. I have each <?php ?> statement separetly but editor didn't accept it. Anyway, I will try to solve it with radiobuttons. :)